# How to store triggered jquery CSS states in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

There's some Javascript that I want to persist when the page is refreshed. The best way of doing this looks like using jquery.cookie.js but from the docs I'm still unclear how to store the Jquery as a variable for the cookie to remember.

The JS Fiddle of the code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sXz3h/2/

What I want to do is as follows:

- Remember the details of the most recently triggered jQuery states so they load on page refresh.

The html looks like

```
<div class="beans">
<div class="range">
<h2>Page title</h2>
<div class="blends blend-two">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Medium number 2">
    <div class="blend-text hide">
        <h3 class="blend-heading">Medium</h3>
        <p class="blend-blurb">Medium roasted. A little more complex with a bigger mouth feel. Clean finish.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blends blend-three">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" alt="Strong number 3">
    <div class="blend-text hide">
        <h3 class="blend-heading">Strong</h3>
        <p class="blend-blurb">Full city roast colour with a chocolate flavour. Rich in taste.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.blend-two').click(function() {
$('.blends').each(function() {
  $('.blends').find('.blend-text').addClass('hide');
  $('.blends').find('img').css('opacity', '.5');
});
$(this).find('.hide').removeClass('hide');
$('.blend-two img').css('opacity', '1');
$('a.active, h2').css('color', '#e0812f');
if ($("div").hasClass("beans")) {
  $('.range').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/600x600)');
} else if ($("div").hasClass("freeze-dried")) {
  $('.range').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/700x700)');
} else {}
});

$('.blend-three').click(function() {
$('.blends').each(function() {
  $('.blends').find('.blend-text').addClass('hide');
  $('.blends').find('img').css('opacity', '.5');
});
$(this).find('.hide').removeClass('hide');
$('.blend-three img').css('opacity', '1');
$('a.active, h2').css('color', '#cf701c');
if ($("div").hasClass("beans")) {
  $('.range').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/800x800)');
} else if ($("div").hasClass("freeze-dried")) {
  $('.range').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/900x900)');
} else {}
});
```

Is the Jquery.cookie.js the best way of doing this, and if so how do I go about storing the states?

Answer (score 1):

If you use HTML5, localStorage would be even easier way to go.

To set it

```
localStorage.setItem('itemName', 'itemValue')
```

To get the value

```
localStorage.getItem('itemName')
```

To remove it

```
localStorage.removeItem('itemName')
```

Example reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: That does look like a better solution. But I'm still confused as to how I would set the storage for the string. How would you parse a Jquery function to the Storage.setItem element?   Storage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("lastname");

Comment: Did you try your solution out? Because it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/fQwjU/

Comment: I couldn't work out how to apply it to my specific problem. I've got someone helping me with the problem though. Will post the solution once completed. Thanks for the suggestion - it's pointed me in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to lesssugar suggesting to use local storage here's the solution I ended up using:

```
$('#blend2').click(function() {

  setState('blend2');
  $('.blends').each(function() {
    $('.blends > .blend-text').addClass('hide');
    $('.blends > img').css('opacity', '.5');
  });

  $('#blend2 .hide').css('display', 'block');
  $('#blend2 > .hide').removeClass('hide');

  $('#blend2 > img').css('opacity', '1');

  $('a.active, h2').css('color', '#e0812f');

  if ($('div').hasClass('beans')) {

    $('#brange').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/600x600)');

  } else if ($("div").hasClass("freeze-dried")) {
    $('#brange').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/700x700)');
  } else {

  }

});

$('#blend3').click(function() {

  setState('blend3');
  $('.blends').each(function() {
    $('.blends').find('.blend-text').css('display', 'none');
    $('.blends').find('.blend-text').addClass('hide');
    $('.blends').find('img').css('opacity', '.5');
  });

  $('#blend3 .hide').css('display', 'block');
  $('#blend3 .hide').removeClass('hide');

  $('#blend3 img').css('opacity', '1');

  $('a.active,h2').css('color', '#cf701c');

  if ($("div").hasClass("beans")) {
    $('#brange').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/800x800)');
  } else if (
    $("div").hasClass("freeze-dried")) {
    $('#brange').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/900x900)');
  } else {

  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var prevState = localStorage.getItem('stateVar');
  //prevState == 'blend3' ? $( "#blend3" ).trigger( "click" ) : $( "#blend2" ).trigger( "click" );
  //console.log( prevState );
  if (prevState == 'blend3') {
    $("#blend3").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $("#blend2").trigger("click");
  }
});


function setState(id) {
  localStorage.setItem('stateVar', id)
}
```

The key to the problem was using a variable to store the page state, then triggering the variable on page load using unique identifiers.

Hope this helps someone. :)